# Why are tulsi leaves used while offering naivedya?

Tags: tradition, tulasi

What is Importance of patri in puja ritual and Why are tulsi leaves used while offering naivedya?

Comment: Related - http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/159/what-is-the-importance-of-the-tulsi-plant-holy-basil/165#165

Answer (score 1):

We often see that while offering naivedya (food offering) to a deity it is offered with the help of two leaves of tulsi. One of them is kept on the naivedya while other is offered to the deity.

Tulsi has the greater capacity to absorb and emit sattvik and Krushnatattva frquencies present in the universe. Therefore use of tulsi while offering naivedya imparts two benefits.

The tulsi leaf used while offering naivedya absorbs the subtle frequencies emitted from the food. When this tulsi leaf is offered to the deity, the deity principle rapidly absorbs the frequencies present in the leaf.

> **Why are women prohibited from gathering tulsi leaves?**
>
> As specified in Dharma texts, women have a high proportion of raja
>   component when compared to men. There is generation of heat energy in
>   the dormant and serene sattvik frequencies present in the tulsi plant
>   by the touch of women which leads to decrease in its sattvikta (sattva
>   quality). Hence they are prohibited from gathering or plucking the
>   tulsi leaves.
>
> **Why are tulsi leaves used while offering naivedya to a deity?**
>
> Thus we have learnt about the gathering of tulsi leaves which imparts
>   spiritual benefits. We often see that while offering naivedya (food
>   offering) to a deity it is offered with the help of two leaves of
>   tulsi. One of them is kept on the naivedya while other is offered to
>   the deity. Let us now understand as to why tulsi leaves are used while
>   offering naivedya to a deity.
>
> Tulsi has the greater capacity to absorb and emit sattvik and
>   Krushnatattva frequencies present in the universe. Therefore use of
>   tulsi while offering naivedya imparts two benefits.
>
> - The tulsi leaf used while offering naivedya absorbs the subtle
>     frequencies emitted from the food. When this tulsi leaf is offered to
>     the deity, the deity principle rapidly absorbs the frequencies present
>     in the leaf.
> - There is subtle covering of raja-tama present in the atmosphere around
>     the food to be offered to the deity as naivedya. When a tulsi leaf is
>     kept on the food, the sattvik frequencies emitted from the tulsi leaf
>     reduces this covering. Besides the atmosphere around the plate or
>     banana leaf meant for serving the naivedya gets purified. This retains
>     the sattvikta of naivedya for a long period.
>
> Thus the tulsi leaf is used for offering naivedya for receiving the
>   grace of the deity by pleasing Him/Her. Therefore there is a rich
>   tradition of offering prayerful obeisance to tulsi plant loved by Shri
>   Vishnu every morning and evening as mark of gratitude because it is a
>   destroyer of negative energies and a purifier of the atmosphere.

[Source](https://www.hindujagruti.org/hinduism/knowledge/article/why-are-tulsi-leaves-used-while-offering-naivedya.html)