# According to scriptures is it allowed to keep Tulasi inside home?

Tags: scripture, tulasi

Tulasi is considered to be [sacred](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/159/what-is-the-importance-of-the-tulsi-plant-holy-basil). Is it allowed to keep it **inside** the home as per the scriptures?

Comment: You must be looking to know whether it is allowed as per scriptures or not?

Comment: Yeah, according to scriptures only! @Rickross

Comment: Then making it more precise (like I hv done) makes sense.

Comment: @Rickross Sure, I will follow it from now onwards.

TiIl now I didn't follow it because I am thinking that any question in this site has that default consideration. Thanks.

Comment: Yes sometimes making the intent clear is needed to avoid ambiguity because people may say you are asking for beliefs or scholars' views, personal opinions etc..

Comment: Absence of scripture tag doesn't mean we are asking for personal opinions or advises. Tags do not define the source which we are looking answers from. The reason could be people thought your question is vague and unclear or not useful. Because plants are to be kept where sunlight fall. Not all sacred beings are brought into our home.

Comment: by inside, do you mean under 4 walls and a roof, or inside the home premises like a garden or sun-room ? because the latter is definitely allowed and recommended, because it is offered during aradhana to the bhagavan in the puja room.

Comment: Under 4 walls and a roof, partial sunroom.... @ram